# While I am trying to detect .xls and .ppt files using Apache Tika, i am getting an error java.lang.NoSuchFieldError : SMALLER_BIG_BLOCK_SIZE_DETAILS

Tags: java, apache-tika

This is the basic detect method that I am using for detecting my msoffice files.

```
Tika tika = new Tika();
TikaInputStream inputStream;
String tikaType="";
inputStream = TikaInputStream.get(fileInputStream);
try {
    tikaType = tika.detect(inputStream);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("TikaStream Find : " +tikaType);
System.out.println("File Extension : " +fileExtension);
```

Stack Trace :-

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SMALLER_BIG_BLOCK_SIZE_DETAILS
org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>
(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:93)
org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>
(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:211)
org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>
(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:167)              
org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.POIFSContainerDetector.
getTopLevelNames(POIFSContainerDetector.java:388)
org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.POIFSContainerDetector.detect
(POIFSContainerDetector.java:451)
org.apache.tika.detect.CompositeDetector.detect
(CompositeDetector.java:84)
org.apache.tika.Tika.detect(Tika.java:156)
org.apache.tika.Tika.detect(Tika.java:203
```

I have tried searching for the solution for this and found many that maybe i have two multiple POI JAR versions in my build path but tried everything but still recieving this error.

Comment: You have two versions of Apache POI on your classpath at *runtime*, check the runtime classpath not the build one

Comment: I checked it but i just have 1 version of Apache POI that is 3.17 .. Can there be any other problem apart from this?

Comment: The exception is clear that you have more than one copy of Apache POI... You'll need to check if something else is bundling a copy of POI, or a jar was renamed etc

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks man I had an older version on my server runtime library. Thanks a lot!